# How can I set a flag value in an array loop?

Tags: java

I have an array as shown below.

Basically in this array, sometimes thebagdata[i].getSecurityType()  may or may not contain values in an array.

```
 for (int i = 0; i <bagdata.length; i++) {
                if (bagdata[i].getSecurityType() != null) {
                    flag = true;
                } else {
                    flag = false;
                }

            }
```

I think that my code is overriding the flag value. How can I deal with this?

Comment: I really don't understand what the problem is...

Comment: Where is the flag relevant? Only inside the for loop or outside too? Also can you elaborate on how the flag is used further in your app?

Comment: As @Mechkov says: tell us what would you like the flag to say. By example "this item meets some condition" (it's used inside the loop), or "there are some item that meets some condition" (it's used then, after the loop).

Comment: Is it possible that you mean that `bagdata[i]` might be `null`, and you want to handle this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depend on what you want to flag, try:

```
boolean flag = true;

for (int i = 0; i <bagdata.length; i++) {
    flag &= bagdata[i].getSecurityType() != null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `break;` immediate after setting the flag if required. If you want flag against each value, make an array of flags.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set flag to true if at least one containsdata you should just set the flag to false before the loop and delete part of else like this:

```
        flag=false;
          for (int i = 0; i <bagdata.length; i++) {
            if (bagdata[i].getSecurityType() != null) {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
```

but if you want to remember flag for each element in array you should create an array of flags...

Answer (score 1):

If you the flag value to be set true then come out of the loop using **break** statement.